# How do I make a n1ql query for the latest record before a certian timestamp

Tags: sql++

Ok, so I have a query that I am trying to implement, but I am at a lost at how to do it.
Basically why I need to do is get the previous state of an account that occurred before a certain timestamp.

So, I have a couchbase server with an `account` doc_type and a `account_history` doctype.
When ever a account document is changed, it creates a new document with the `account_history` doctype with it's previous state, nothing is allowed to alter any `account_history` documents.

Each document has `last_updated_timestamp`, which is the time in epoch.

so for example I have a `account` document of

```
{
    id: 1
    username: "abc",
    password: "encrypted",
    data: "A",
    last_updated_timestamp: "1577924929"
}
{
    id: 2
    username: "abc",
    password: "encrypted",
    data: "A",
    last_updated_timestamp: "1577924929"
}
```

and I have a `account_history` documents of

```
{
    id: 1
    username: "abc",
    password: "encrypted",
    data: "D",
    last_updated_timestamp: "1277924929"
},
{
    id: 1
    username: "abc",
    password: "encrypted",
    data: "B",
    last_updated_timestamp: "1177924929"
},
{
    id: 1
    username: "abc",
    password: "encrypted3",
    data: "A",
    last_updated_timestamp: "1077924929"
},
{
    id: 2
    username: "abc",
    password: "encrypted",
    data: "D",
    last_updated_timestamp: "1277924929"
},
{
    id: 2
    username: "abc",
    password: "encrypted",
    data: "B",
    last_updated_timestamp: "1177924929"
},
{
    id: 2
    username: "abc",
    password: "encrypted3",
    data: "A",
    last_updated_timestamp: "1077924929"
}
```

and I want to get the latest record before a timestamp of 1200000000, resulting in

```
{
    id: 1
    username: "abc",
    password: "encrypted",
    data: "B",
    last_updated_timestamp: "1177924929"
},
{
    id: 2
    username: "abc",
    password: "encrypted",
    data: "B",
    last_updated_timestamp: "1177924929"
}
```

Comment: Added requirement for getting multiple account's last update instead of just one.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to query from history only

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON default(last_updated_timestamp DESC) 
         WHERE doc_type = "account_history";
CREATE INDEX ix2 ON default(last_updated_timestamp DESC) 
         WHERE doc_type = "account";

SELECT h.* 
FROM default AS h
WHERE h.doc_type = "account_history" AND h.last_updated_timestamp < "1200000000"
ORDER BY h.last_updated_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;
```

For all accounts

```
SELECT MAX([h.last_updated_timestamp,h])[1].*
FROM default AS h
WHERE h.doc_type = "account_history" AND h.last_updated_timestamp < "1200000000"
GROUP BY h.id;
```

If you need from any one of them

```
SELECT h1.* 
FROM (SELECT h.* 
      FROM default AS h
      WHERE h.doc_type = "account_history" AND h.last_updated_timestamp < "1200000000"
      ORDER BY h.last_updated_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT h.* 
       FROM default AS h
       WHERE h.doc_type = "account" AND h.last_updated_timestamp < "1200000000"
       ORDER BY h.last_updated_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)
      ) AS h1
 ORDER BY h1.last_updated_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Another solution is ORDER BY + LIMIT 1  vs MAX(). If query uses Index Order ORDER BY is perform better.

Comment: Nice idea, but I need to get the last update for all accounts.

Comment: Use GROUP BY id with MAX. Updated the post for  all accounts

Answer (score 1):

When we are refer to ANSI/ISO Join, then it could be following statement:

```
Select h1.*
From `account_history` h1
Join
    (Select id, max(last_updates_timestamp) timestamp
     From `account_history`
     Where last_updated_timestamp < "1200000000"
     Group by id) h2
  On
    (h1.id = h2.id) and
    (h1.last_updated_timestamp = h2.timestamp)
Where
    h1.last_updated_timestamp < "1200000000"
```

For query performance tuning, it needs to create an index consists of id and last_updated_timestamp.

Cheers and Enjoy!